# How can i upload a link to a href function through the admin panel in django?

Tags: django-models, django-templates, python-3.9

i have made a models file that posts to the index template through the admin panel. I just made it [this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXAaP.png) so you can access it by clicking the download button. But after clicking download it shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4p4Z.png). How do i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your href attribute is now interpreted as a relative path. If you want it to redirect you to external site add "https://" at the start of it just like that:

```
href="https://{{ i.app_download_link }}"
```